# Built-in method to send an array of floats from node.js to the browser via HTTP request compactly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, http

Is there a default/standard function on Node.js's library to send a big array of floats as an answer of an HTTP request compactly? That is, it must be sent as an array of bytes instead of a JSON string.

Comment: You can simply return an array and have your server gzip buy why dont you want to use JSON?

Comment: JSON with gzip content encoding is good enough for most purposes. I would think you'd incur a much higher performance penalty by unpacking the binary array than what what browser does for you with native gzip decoding and JSON parsing.

Comment: It is a huge (1~10mb+) array of floats which consists in 90~99% of the size of the site.

Comment: Why not JSON?  If you go binary, you're going to have work to do to make sure you have a platform-safe binary format and work to read it on the other end in that platform-safe way.  That's all doable, but extra work that JSON solves for you.

Comment: Who is consuming the data? Your application or a web app? Javascript engine in browser is inherently not good at handling binaries.

Comment: The "data" is actually a huge library of source code in binary lambda calculus, the idea is to send everything to the client at once so he has access to it all enabling the compiler to perform interesting whole-program-optimizations. So the fact I'm sending all that data means I have to cut as much as I can from its size when it is actually sent. That is why I think just using JSON isn't a good idea. I'm asking because I'm not sure what is the right way to approach compacting that, considering the weird way JS handles numbers, without a proper integer type...

Comment: Like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FSending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data